# How To delete from both database and datagridview

Tags: c#, sql

So i've been looking around the google for the anwser to this found so many diffrenet anwsers but i do not quite understand them and dont really see the way to implement them even thoug i have tryed alot so my issue is basicly that my delete button only deletes from the datagridview and not the database itself i do have the gridview bound to my knowledge but this is the very first form app i make so im a bit puzzeld to what i am doing

```
    private void buttonDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {///////////////////////////////////////////////////////issue is here
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
        }
        //string del = "DELETE FROM Data WHERE RowID = @RowID";
    }
        using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring))
        {
            string query = "insert into data(Navn, NummerPlade, KMKørt, dato)";
            query += " values (@Navn, @NummerPlade, @KMKørt, @dato)";
            Connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Navn", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NummerPlade", textBox8.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KMKørt", textBox6.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dato", textBox7.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Connection.Close();
            button4_Click(sender, e);
        }
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /// Connect / Update


        using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring))
        {

            Connection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM  Data", Connection);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sqlDa.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
        }
        buttonConn.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: "my issue is basicly that my delete button only deletes from the datagridview" ...you haven't got any code which would run a SQL DELETE. You've got one string, commented out, relating to it, but nothing to actually execute that SQL. Judging by the (randomly inserted, so it won't compile) `using` block just below, you know how to execute a SQL statement...so what's stopping you doing that with a DELETE instead? It's unclear what you tried - if anything - or what the issue actually is.

Comment: Look into the Update method of the DataAdapter.

Comment: The DGV is not getting repainted after you update.  The trick is to set it to null : dataGridView1.DataSource = null; dataGridView1.DataSource = data;

Comment: @ADyson my appolegies for not explaining it right i wannet to make my button delete the selected row but have no idea how to find the seleted row (seleted by clicking on it with mouse cursor)

my newest attempt to delete it
                     string del = "DELETE FROM Data WHERE RowID = @RowID";
                Connection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(del, Connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RowID", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Connection.Close();

Comment: Presumably somewhere in your row there is a field which contains the ID? You need to read that field from the selected row. You can use the `item.Index` to find the row, and then get the value of the ID field from within that.

Comment: string del = "DELETE FROM Data WHERE RowID = @RowID";
                    Connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(del, Connection);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RowID",Convert.ToInt32(item.Index));
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

its now telling me invalid column name 'RowID'. @ADyson also thx for the help getting me this far

Comment: well I have no idea whether your database table contains a field called RowID or not. The error is telling you that it doesn't. So check your field names. Also I seriously doubt that the item.Index will correspond to the actual ID of the row in the table - especially if some rows have been deleted, or you're not showing all the rows to begin with. The Index is simply a count of how many rows down the list in the gridview the row is, it is not related to the original data source. like I said, if you have a _field_ within your gridview that holds the ID, that's where you need to get the ID from.